# How do you shut Dr. Watson reporting off on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have the dreaded "dw20.exe" process running wild on my Windows Server 2008.  This is Dr. Watson error reporting, and when it comes up, it absolutely *pegs* the CPU.

It's a known problem and there are several solutions...for every OS except Server 2008, it seems.  Here's the Microsoft KB topic on it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841477

That has a list of registry keys to change, but they don't exist in Server 2008 (it was written for everything up to 2003).  I did find a "PCHealth" key somewhere else in the registry, but I try not to just root around and change stuff randomly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Microsoft TechNet -- [**Windows Error Reporting and the Problem Reports and Solutions Feature in Windows Server 2008**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732067%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

when in doubt, use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). I have solved many problems thanks to it, should be installed by default as one of the system tools.